# open .mat file with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, mat-file

i'm looking for an equivalent to this python 3.6 code :

```
import scipy.io as sio
file = sio.loadmat('file.mat')
data = file['data']
```

I have to do the same thing in python 2.7, i tryed

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('file.mat')
```

But it doesn't work, do you have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use the SciPy approach? SciPy supports Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use scipy, you can use h5py. It support Matlab arrays saved as v3.7 arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py 

f = h5py.File('file.mat','r') 
data = f.get('data/variable_name') 

# convert to numpy array
data = np.array(data)
```

Save the data from Matlab like so `save('filename', '-v7.3', 'var1');`